# Populate ACF 2nd select field in a repeater based from 1st select field value ID

Tags: select, dynamic, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I am trying to populate Select#2 based from value of Select#1. But I could not get the selected value id on select#1 both are in a repeater. This will be in the admin page.

```
function dynamic_manager_select($fields) {

    if (have_rows('job_location_repeater')) {
        
        while (have_rows('job_location_repeater')) {
            the_row();
            $locationID = get_sub_field('job_location' );
        }

        if (!empty($locationID)) {
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'center_hr',
                'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'hr_location', 
                        'value' => $locationID,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                ),
            );
            
            $center_hr_query = new WP_Query($args);
            
            if ($center_hr_query->have_posts()) {
                while ($center_hr_query->have_posts()) {
                    $center_hr_query->the_post();
            
                    $taxonomy_terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'hr-department');
            
                    if ($taxonomy_terms && !is_wp_error($taxonomy_terms)) {
                        // Loop through and display the terms
                        foreach ($taxonomy_terms as $term) {
                            // $options .= '<option value="'.$term->slug.'">'.$term->name.'</option>';
                            $fields['choices'][ $term->slug ] = $term->name;
                        }
                    }
                }
                wp_reset_postdata();
            } 
        }
    }
    

    return $fields;
}

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=select_department', 'dynamic_manager_select');
```

[image: Admin view]

Here is the view in the admin.